# Rename long column names for dbf conversion

Tags: arcobjects, dbf

Is there an ArcObjects API call that will rename long column name? If a column name is too long for conversion to a .dbf file, I want rename to a valid length.

I have searched ArcObjects help. Either such a function does not exist, or my search terms are not getting it done.

I did find a field validation function.

If no such function exists, is there a algorithm or renaming standard I could reference to roll my own?

Comment: The "table manager" plugin for QGis does it, the code is at https://github.com/borysiasty/tablemanager (licensed under GPLv2).

Comment: @Mike Henderson, What is the use case for this question (e.g. custom user form where user is creating fields, or some data conversion process from DB table to shapefile)?

Comment: @artwork21 Your example is on the mark. A user form to move data from source to destination. If the destination is a .dbf file, I need to rename long column names.

Comment: @artwork21 I want to rename long names based on some standard naming convention, if it exists.

Comment: There is no standard naming convention to make longer than ten character names fit within 10 characters (short of truncate, then use digits if there's more than one).  Anything clever would require human intervention (and an understanding of the domain in which it was deployed).  Personally, I'd recommend avoiding shapefiles for database export, since it's not only the names that get mangled, the datatypes and values do as well.

Comment: @Vince, Point taken, but the policy you suggest is not my call. :}

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would agree with @Vince's comment, avoid using shapefiles. But if you still want to rename fields then if you are using 10.2.2 you can call the geo-processing tool [Alter Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Alter_Field/001700000198000000/) using the [IGeoProcessor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000003rr000000) interface. Your source data must be in a geodatabase which it must be if you are wanting to shorten them.